# how to configure openldap slapd.conf to use nis.schema

Tags: openldap

all, noob openldap question here.

trying to import a posixaccount entry into openldap. from reading, most recommendations are to include "include /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema" into slapd.conf.

i am using the yum installation of openldap-server (2.4.44).

the yum installation doesn't provide /etc/openldap/slapd.conf, so i created a custom slapd.conf, updated /etd/sysconfig/slapd (SLAPD_OPTS) to use it, and restarted - result is below. It isn't working correctly, and looks like using slapd.conf is deprecated in this release.

So, back to original problem: i need to import a posixaccount object into the yum installation of openldap 2.4.44.

any comments welcome, thanks v much for your time on this, mr

```
[root@ccycloud openldap]# cat /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
logfile /var/tmp/slapd.log
loglevel 1344
include /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/collective.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/corba.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/duaconf.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/dyngroup.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/java.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/openldap.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/pmi.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/ppolicy.schema

[root@ccycloud openldap]# slaptest -f slapd.conf
config file testing succeeded

# edit /etc/sysconfig/slapd (add -f slapd.conf to SLAPD_OPTS)

SLAPD_OPTIONS="-f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf"



RESULT is errors in /var/log/messages:

Jun 10 20:02:46 ccycloud systemd: Starting OpenLDAP Server Daemon...
Jun 10 20:02:46 ccycloud check-config.sh: Warning: Usage of a configuration file is obsolete!
Jun 10 20:02:47 ccycloud systemd: Can't open PID file /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
```

Comment: "the yum installation doesn't provide /etc/openldap/slapd.conf,": that's because it is using dynamic configuration, and so should you, as the first warning message says. The PID file problem is self-explanatory, and none of this has anything to do with `nis.schema`.

Comment: Thanks @user207421, i have posted a procedure below if you would care to comment on additional info, would appr, otherwise thanks again, mr

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is my final effort, but i have a working model now.
the following is a procedure from default immediately following yum installation of openldap-servers, and using ldapadd to add the additional schemas. i include a couple of tree outlines to illustrate effect on the file system and the new databases created.
thnx very much for your time on this. mr

```
[root@ccycloud openldap]# pwd
/etc/openldap
[root@ccycloud openldap]# tree slapd.d
slapd.d
├── cn=config
│   ├── cn=schema
│   │   └── cn={0}core.ldif
│   ├── cn=schema.ldif
│   ├── olcDatabase={0}config.ldif
│   ├── olcDatabase={-1}frontend.ldif
│   ├── olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif
│   └── olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif
└── cn=config.ldif

[root@ccycloud openldap]# ldapadd -H ldapi:/// -f schema/cosine.ldif 
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
adding new entry "cn=cosine,cn=schema,cn=config"

[root@ccycloud openldap]# ldapadd -H ldapi:/// -f schema/nis.ldif 
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
adding new entry "cn=nis,cn=schema,cn=config"

[root@ccycloud openldap]# slapcat -b "cn=config" | less
[root@ccycloud openldap]# tree slapd.d
slapd.d
├── cn=config
│   ├── cn=schema
│   │   ├── cn={0}core.ldif
│   │   ├── cn={1}cosine.ldif
│   │   └── cn={2}nis.ldif
│   ├── cn=schema.ldif
│   ├── olcDatabase={0}config.ldif
│   ├── olcDatabase={-1}frontend.ldif
│   ├── olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif
│   └── olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif
└── cn=config.ldif

etc .....
```